# How to install php-curl in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, ubuntu-16.04, php-curl

Upgraded to `Ubuntu 16.04` and facing problem after installing `PHP5`.

**Installed PHP-5 with following:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5.5   # for PHP 5.5
```

Trying to install php-curl but its not working.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

> Error: E: Unable to locate package php5-curl

Comment: are you sure it's not installedand not just disabled? use `php5enmod` command to enable it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use php 5.5? It's reached it's end of life, and is no longer supported (There are many security issues)

Comment: @frankerZ My projects not working under PHP7

Comment: Are these huge projects? I think you should lean toward making your projects work in the latest version, then installing an old php to support this project.

Comment: I've 15-20 projects on local and live servers not in my hand

Answer (score 268, accepted):

**In Ubuntu 16.04 default PHP version is 7.0, if you want to use different version then you need to install PHP package according to PHP version:**

- PHP 7.4: `sudo apt-get install php7.4-curl`
- PHP 7.3: `sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl`
- PHP 7.2: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl`
- PHP 7.1: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl`
- PHP 7.0: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`
- PHP 5.6: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`
- PHP 5.5: `sudo apt-get install php5.5-curl`

Comment: For me, this was exactly the case. Had PHP 7 installed and kept getting `Package 'php5-curl' has no installation candidate`. Running `sudo apt-get install php-curl` fixed the problem

Comment: use `php -version` to find out what version of PHP you're on

Comment: Perfect, but how do you fix libcurl issues with PHP 7.2 (needs libcurl4) and Percona MySQL 5.7 (needs libcurl3)?

Comment: @ShadowZzz yes, your suggestion worked for me as well.

Comment: It seems, that these versions are no longer part of ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Comment: Yes, this works without having to specify a PHP version if the user doesn't know it.

Comment: Worked for me too on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 21):

This works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

Answer (score 7):

Do:

```
apt-get update
```

And then:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php8.0-curl
```

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 18.04 or PHP 7.2 users you can do:

`apt-get install php7.2-curl`

You can check your PHP version by running `php -v` to verify your PHP version and get the right curl version.

Answer (score 2):

To Install cURL 7.49.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 and Derivatives

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.49.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf curl-7.49.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.49.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

and restart the web browser.

You can check the modules by running `php -m | grep curl`