# sudo apt-get install php-curl install error

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, curl

While writing my registration code, I am using the command:

> $ch = curl_init();

but am getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   curl_init()

Tried Installing curl on ubuntu using

> sudo apt-get install php-curl

but am getting the following

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done php-curl is already the newest version
>   (1:7.2+62+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 154 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or
>   removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be
>   used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y Setting up mysql-server-5.7
>   (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) ... Checking if update is needed. Checking
>   server version. Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
>   mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at
>   row 1 mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5 dpkg: error processing
>   package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):  subprocess installed
>   post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency
>   problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:  mysql-server depends
>   on mysql-server-5.7; however:   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not
>   configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the
>   error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                             Errors were encountered while processing:  mysql-server-5.7  mysql-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
>   an error code (1)

What should I do?

Tried restarting apache anyway but that doesn't work either
I also tried all suggestions as per [How to install php-curl in Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800606/how-to-install-php-curl-in-ubuntu-16-04) Nothing is working.