# Ubuntu PHP 5 Install Curl Cannot Find Package

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm getting a PHP Fatal error:

```
Call to undefined function curl_init() error while testing some PHP code on my server.
```

I assumed Curl needed to be installed so i found the PHP version first:

```
php --version
PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 (cli)
```

I proceeded to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-curl
```

I then tried:

```
sudo apt install php-curl
```

and it appeared to install but I saw references to PHP 7 and it completed successfully.

Yet, the problem persists.

How do I get curl running to stop the init() error?

UPDATE:  When I run this I get:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.13).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 172 not upgraded.
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800606/how-to-install-php-curl-in-ubuntu-16-04) if it helps

Comment: do you have curl itself installed? `sudo apt-get install curl`. did you restart the server? `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: @wrested a bear once
sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.13).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 172 not upgraded.

Comment: What linux distribution is running on your server? How did you install php@5.6.11? I suspect that your distribution only provides php@7, yet you or somebody else manually installed php@5 on it.

Comment: @k0pernikus how do I find the distribution?

Comment: Try `uname -a` or in case it's an Ubuntu, `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
@k0pernikus

Comment: The generic cURL package might be needed in addition, but it does not replace the PHP extension

Comment: According to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/PHP/, Ubuntu 16.04 ships with PHP 7.0, and it does not serve any older PHP versions. Probably, you have removed the package sources for another PHP version already?

Comment: @NicoHaase how do I add them back?

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt php5.6-curl`? I assume you have `ppa:ondrej/php` repository setup on that server.

Comment: @k0pernikus E: Invalid operation php5.6-curl

Answer (score 1):

You are using Ubuntu@16.04. 16.04 does not ship with php@5 but with php@7.

If you need your older version of php and its dependencies, you have to install it differently.

There is a [trustworthy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869819/using-an-unofficial-php-ppa-on-a-production-server) (note: *any external repository* may still be a *security thread*) repository maintained by ondrej, namely:

- [ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

I have build a Dockerfile using 16.04 to showcase how you could install php@5.6 and php5.6-curl:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get -qq install software-properties-common > /dev/null && \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y > /dev/null && \
    apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install php5.6 php5.6-curl > /dev/null
RUN php -v && php -m | grep curl
```

This Dockerfile is not ideal, yet the last run prints:

```
PHP 5.6.40-8+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
curl
```

showing that it has php@5.6 and php-curl@5.6 installed.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  So does this replace the existing php7 entirely and potentially break any other code on the server relying on PHP7 or it's extensions?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco That's actually a good follow-up question that you could ask while linking to this question. I never had the use-case of having to run different versions of php on the same server and I strongly advise against that.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Google search brought this to light: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/php-multiple-versions-ubuntu-16-04-17-10

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. First Install CURL by typing `sudo apt-get install curl`.
2. Then Restart Apache by typing `sudo service apache2 restart`.
3. Install PHP5 CURL `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`.
4. Restart Apache by typing `sudo service apache2`.

Comment: As per the question `E: Unable to locate package php5-curl`